# React:Uncaught TypeError: Expecting a function in instanceof check, but got #<Object>

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm new to React and have just played around with update timer example

```
var Timer = React.createClass({
  displayName: 'Timer',
  getInitialState: function() {
    return {secondsElapsed: 0};
  },
  tick: function() {
    console.log("tick", this.isMounted())
    if (this.isMounted()) {
      this.setState({secondsElapsed: this.state.secondsElapsed + 1});   
    }
  },
  componentWillMount: function() {
    this.interval = setInterval(this.tick, 1000);
  },
  componentWillUnmount: function() {
    clearInterval(this.interval);
  },
  render: function() {
    return (
      React.DOM.div(null, "Seconds Elapsed: ", this.state.secondsElapsed)
    );
  }
});

React.renderComponent(Timer(null), document.body);
```

However I'm coming across an error, the first tick works and I see it render from 0 to 1 but after that I get the following errors.

on V0.8 I get this error

> Uncaught Error: Invariant Violation: replaceState(...): Cannot update during an existing state transition (such as within render). This could potentially cause an infinite loop so it is forbidden.

v0.9 displays this error

> Uncaught TypeError: Expecting a function in instanceof check, but got #

If I do a console log in the renderer function of this.state.secondsElapsed it will continue to increment every second. Its only when I attempt to reference it in the return value that it will error.

What am I missing?

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem. Does http://jsbin.com/pufiseqe/1/edit work for you? If not, what browser are you in?

Comment: That works, so it isn't my browser or the code. Has to be my setup,  I'll play around with it and see if it's another script or an earlier cleanup method. Just odd that the first tick worked and no other code is executed between that and the 2nd tick.

Comment: Okay. If you can provide a reduced test case I'm happy to look at the problem. If you could post a stack trace of the error you're getting in 0.9, that would help too.

Comment: OK on further investigation when I remove the import for prototype.js react works as intended. http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/prototype/1.7.0.0/prototype.js

Comment: Thanks for letting me know. I'm guessing that [#1180](https://github.com/facebook/react/pull/1180), which was merged this week, fixes your problem.